# Finding solutions to $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{701}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Solve the congruence
> $$x^2\equiv -1 \pmod{701}$$

I have proven that $2$ is a primitive root modulo $701$ but I am not sure how to use this fact.

Comment: Well, you know the order of $2$ modulo $701$, and $x$ must be $2^k$ for some $k$. Now note that $x^4 = (x^2)^2 \equiv (-1)^2 = 1\pmod{701}$.

Comment: Hint: $701$ is a prime number. $x=135,566$ modulo $701$.

Comment: You do not need a primitive root.  You need only a nonquadratic residue.  Since $701\not\in\{1,7\}\bmod 8$, one such nonquadratic residue is $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Legendre symbol is given by
$$
\left( \frac{-1}{701}\right)=(-1)^{700/2}=1,
$$
where $p=701$ is prime. Hence there exist indeed solutions.

We have $y=2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=2^{350} \equiv -1 \bmod 701$ so that $x^2\equiv -1\bmod 701$ for $x\equiv 2^{175}\equiv 566 \bmod 701$. So $x=566$ and $x=-566=135$ are the two solutions (modulo $701)$.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on how you got $y=2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=2^{350} \equiv -1 \bmod 701$? Thanks!

Comment: We have $2^{p-1}\equiv 1 \bmod p$ for primes $p>2$ by Fermat. Now we can try to consider a square root, i.e., $2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$.